# iOS toolbar hidden in naviation controller even though I've specified self.navigationController.toolbarHidden to NO?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am having trouble getting a toolbar I've added to a UIViewController using StoryBoard to show up. I did a search and found several answers saying to set:

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
```

I did this on the init, and even tried it on the load, and then even tried with a button to make sure I wasn't crazy. But no matter what I do, I can't get the toolbar to show in the UIViewController.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did u hide the toolbar before? how did u add the viewcontroller, to a tabbarcontroller?

Comment: No - I did not hide the toolbar. I added a toolbar, not a tabbarcontroller. I added it by dragging it onto the view from the storyboard.

Comment: Does your Storyboard have an embedded UINavigationController?